# What is the difference between Messagebox,Dialog and ModalMessage?

Tags: delphi

I am new to program so I am following expert's foot steps but I am kinda lost here

```
 ShowMessage('Hello World');
 MessageBox(null,'Hello World'mb_OK(1));
ShowModal('Hello World');
```

I know it's not correct Delphi syntax.

What is the difference between the three

```
 MessageBox()
 ShowMessage()
 ShowModal()
```

All I know is that I have used ShowMessage a lot and the message comes on a small form with OK button.

Which one of the above uses the API

```
  User32.MessageBoxW
  User32.MessageBoxA
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a modal messagebox is one that blocks you cant perform any action in the main windows unless you close this messagebox

a non modal messagebox doesnt block you can close it any time you wish and can continue to work in the main window

a MessageBox is a generic form if you provide the HWnd parameter it can be Modal if you provide null (as you show ) it will be nonmodal

all will reach user32!messagebox or its internals

it should be prestty easy for you to check by setting a breakpoint

and this question of yours will also likely be closed as unclear or lacks basic understanding